# Animation In Petersen Graph

Tags: animations

I want to produce animation which indicate cycle of length 5 in Petersen graph.I tried the following code but it indicate only single edges.I want to produce animation with all edges.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{animate}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tkz-graph}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
 \usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
 \usepackage[paperheight=11cm,paperwidth=11cm,bottom=0cm,top=0.21cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}



\begin{document}


\begin{animateinline}[controls,autoplay,loop]{2}
\multiframe{12}{n=18+72}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {18,90,...,306}
{
\draw(\x:5cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
\draw(\x:3cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
\draw(\x:5cm) [line width=3pt]-- (\x+72:5cm);
\draw(\x:3cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x+144:3cm);
\draw(\x:5cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x:3cm);
}
\draw(\n:5cm)[line width=7pt,color=blue]--(\n+72:5cm);  \end{tikzpicture}    
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to produce animation which indicate cycle of length 4.I tried the above code but the it shaded to single edges.I want an animation which shade all edges of cycle.

Comment: I am not familiar with Petersen graphs nor with what a *cycle* means here. That is why I am asking. Up to now, I can see the outer edges being coloured blue one by one, one at a time. Do you want them to be successively coloured blue until all of them are blue, and if so, in which order? What about the nodes?

Comment: A cycle of four length means sequence of four edges whose starting and ending node is same.In above code outer edges being colored one by one.But i want colored them continuously.Say suppose in first frame it should color one edge(say edge-1) and in next frame it should color two edges(say edge-1 and edge-2) like wise....And animation can be start from any of the node.

Answer (score 2):

This colours the outer edges continuously:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tkz-graph}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
%\usepackage[paperheight=11cm,paperwidth=11cm,bottom=0cm,top=0.21cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,autoplay,loop]{2}
\multiframe{6}{i=0+1,n=-54+72}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {18,90,...,306}
  {
    \draw(\x:5cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
    \draw(\x:3cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
    \draw(\x:5cm) [line width=3pt]-- (\x+72:5cm);
    \draw(\x:3cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x+144:3cm);
    \draw(\x:5cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x:3cm);
  }
  \ifnum\i>0
    \ifnum\i=1
      \xdef\cycle{\n}
    \else
      \xdef\cycle{\cycle,\n}
    \fi
    \foreach \x in \cycle
    {
      \draw(\x:5cm)[line width=7pt,color=blue]--(\x+72:5cm);
    }
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}    
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this what you want?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Animation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    mydot/.style={circle, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum width=10pt},
    line width=3pt]

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \i using int(\x)] in {18,90,...,306}
{
 \node[mydot=blue, visible on=<1->] (out-\i) at (\x:4cm) {};
 \node[mydot=red, visible on=<2->] (in-\i) at (\x:2cm) {};
}

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using {int(mod(\i+72,360))},
                evaluate=\i as \j using {int(mod(\i+144,360))}]
                in {18,90,...,306}{
   \draw[visible on=<4->] (out-\i) -- (in-\i);
    \draw[visible on=<3->] (out-\i)--(out-\k);
   \draw[visible on=<5->] (in-\i)--(in-\j);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

[image]